# List all variables that are less than or equal to X

Tags: java

I want to list variables such as water, popcorn, candy, juice, etc. I have around 30 variables in this list. I need to set up a way that after a user inputs their total currency it will list how many of each item they can buy. For example:

```
int money = user.nextint();
System.out.println("With " + money + " dollars you can buy" +
                   "# of Popcorn or # number of candy or # of juice etc");
```

Would a multi-dimensional array be the best way? I'll add a few ideas below

```
System.out.println("You can buy " + item1/Money + " popcorn.");
```

I figure I can add each item manually and divide its cost by the money. However obviously this would be extremely tedious for 30+ items and I'm just curious if there is a more effective way.

Also I do not want to include items that are NOT affordable. I'd like to exclude those from my `println`. Which my only theory on that includes A LOT of `if` and `if-else` statements.

Comment: just run a few divisions, for each that returns a value over 1, print a line with the result. what more do you need?

Comment: If you only want to print the results and calculate each item independently from the other, you don't need any array!? Just loop through the items and calculate how man can be bought with the available money.

Comment: Don't worry about making your question brief. Please expand your problem as detailed as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a class which holds an item and it's price. Maintain a list of items, then iterate over them and calculate the quantity for each.

```
class Item
{
    public final String name;
    public final int price;

    public Item(final String name, final int price)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQty(final int budget)
    {
        return budget / price;
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        final List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
            new Item("Popcorn", 10_000), // always a rip-off
            new Item("Water", 1),
            new Item("Juice", 3)
        );

        final int money = 10;

        for (final Item item : items)
        {
            final int qty = item.getQty(money);
            if (qty > 0) // exclude things we can't buy
            {
                System.out.println("You can buy " + qty + " " + item.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this for sure. It may take me a bit to incorporate this into my code but I'll add feedback ASAP. My poor brain is getting hiccups at this point. Too big of a task for my first week @.@

Comment: I know this may be silly, but how may I call the List<Item> from a different class if I chose to write this string in, for example the items.java class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
   public static  class Item {
      private double price;
      private String itemName;
      //  getter setter
   }

   public static void list( List<Item> availableItems, double money ) {
     for( Item item : availableItems ) {
         if( item.getPrice() <= money ) {
            System.out.println("You can buy " + ( int ) ( money / item.getPrice() ) + " " + item.getItemName() );
         }
     }

     // java 8 code is as below

     // availableItems.forEach( item -> { if( item.getPrice() <= money ) {
     //       System.out.println("You can buy " + ( int ) ( money / item.getPrice() ) + " " + item.getItemName() );
     //    } } );

   public static void main(String[] str ) {

       List<Item> availableItems = null;
       double money;
       // to do code for item initialization
       // get user input for money
      list ( availableItems, money );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here some Code that could help you.

Item Class

```
public class Item {

  private String name;
  private double price;

  public Item(String name, double price) {

    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getName() {

    return name;
  }

  public double getPrice() {

    return price;
  }
}
```

Main

```
Item[] items = new Item[]{
  new Item("Popcorn", 2.5),
  new Item("Water", 1.0),
  new Item("Candy", 3.0),
  new Item("DVD", 14.5),
  ...
};

double credit = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Credit: " + credit + "$");

for(Item item : items) {

  if(credit > item.getPrice()) System.out.println((int) (credit / item.getPrice()) + "x " + item.getName() + "(" + item.getPrice() + "$) -> " + (credit % item.getPrice()) + "$");
}
```

Output

```
// For example    

Credit: 12.5$
5x Popcorn(2.5$) -> 0.0$
12x Water(1.0$) -> 0.5$
4x Candy(3.0$) -> 0.5$
```

Non-affordable items will not be issued

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int totalCurrency = 30;
        HashMap<String, Integer> itemsMap = new HashMap<>();
        itemsMap.put("Water", 30);
        itemsMap.put("Popcorn", 10);
        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> itemSet = itemsMap.entrySet();
        String output = "With " + totalCurrency + " dollars you can buy ";
        for (Entry entry : itemSet) {
            if ((Integer) entry.getValue() <= totalCurrency) {
                int temp = totalCurrency / (Integer) entry.getValue();
                output += temp + " of " + entry.getKey() + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```